# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for ABCpdf8

Tags: abcpdf

Thanks in advance.

I have ran into an issue with ABCpdf. I continuously receive the following exception, when I try to add image URL to pdf. This was working fine some days back but its not working now.

**WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.PDFException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Int32 AddUrl(System.String, Boolean, Int32, Boolean) at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url)**

This is working for content without image but content with multiple images does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @DavidAleu check if there are errors in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error crept up in my case was that there was an exception occurring in code behind. I have rectified the exception and everything was working well.

Answer (score 0):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   abcpdf

After hours for troubleshooting, modifying IIS and all sorts of things...
It turns out (in our case v.7 abcpdf) the IE 9 is not supported, after downgrading back to IE 8 the print works.